# How could I specify assignee while using git push option to create a MR?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to create a MR via the command line and specify the assignee at the same time.

I know the following cmd can create a MR to the target branch.

```py
git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=develop
```

However, is there any option that can enable me to specify the assignee?
For example, I've tried but it never works.

```py
git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=develop -o merge_request.assignee=0 #(or whatever)
```

Comment: According to the doc https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-merge-requests, there's not such push option yet. You could try gitlab api to do the job. `python-gitlab` is a user-friendly tool.